# Dropline menu without JS

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I've been searching for a dropline menu without JS - but without any luck. 
I'm trying to build a menu like the one on [vimeo.com](http://vimeo.com), but the most tutorials about making a dropline is using something like this:

```
.submenu { display:none; }
li.item:hover > .submenu { display:block; }
```

Insted I would like to use overflow:hidden; to show the submenu.
Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tuplet/Jv77L/

In this example I've used jQuery to determine the height of #top from 40px to 80px when you hover a list item. This is actually my main problem because I don't know how to do this without jQuery? How can I make the #top height change when hovering a li?

I don't know if it's possible (or the best way) but let me know if you have an idea :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the javascript, add this to your css:

```
#top:hover { 
    height:80px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough about that. It should only expand when you hover the "li", and not the whole topbar :)

Comment: Are 'Link 2.1' and 'Link 2.2' a subitems of 'Link 2',
is 'Link 2.11' a subitem of 'Link 2.1'
and is 'Link 2.21' a subitem of 'Link 2.2'?

Can you also tell me which links are visible if you hover a certain link?

Comment: I understand why you're questionin the list syntax, because I made a mistake by closing the <li> without having the <ul> tags indside of it. Thanks for mentioning it!
The idea is, that you hover the parent li, and then the sub-menu appears one level at the time.

Comment: Yeah, that the same solution that I mentioned in my main question. But I'm seeking the same effect as Vimeo.com with a "overflow:hidden" effect.
But what effect would to add to your example so make it slide down? There is no CSS transition effect for "display:none;" to "display:block;".

Comment: I don't think that's possible with css.   
However, it is possible with javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Seems like I have to use jQuery and then the "display:none / block;" method for people without JS. :-/